# How do i read from a text file in resources folder and output into array

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a text file that is within the code folder so it moves around with the code and i want to read everything in it and output it into and array here what i have so far but it doesn't seem to work

```
            String strAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
            String strFilePath = Path.Combine(strAppPath, "Words");
            String strFullFilename = Path.Combine(strFilePath, "Negative.text");

            string[] Negative_Words = File.ReadLines(strFullFilename).ToArray();
            string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Negative_Words);
            MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
```

i keep getting an error saying the file could not be found

[This is an image of where the text file is located the file is Negative.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN8k2.png)

Comment: They're probably not copied to the output directory.

Comment: They are all set to copy always

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to read the txt files in the folder.

```
    string path = "../../Words/School.txt";
    string []arr = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    string todisplay= string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr);
    Console.WriteLine(todisplay);
```

txt file located:

[image]

Result:

[image]